# SQL Query Does not retrieving data when try to join three tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, sql-server-2008

This is my ERD for my database contains three tables:

[image]

I want to retrieve data from this tables, So I wrote following Query:

```
SELECT [SrvcDate], [Order].OrderID, [EmployeeID], [CustID], [ComputerID]
FROM [Order], [OtherService], [ServiceOrder]
WHERE [Order].[OrderID]=[OtherService].[OrderID]
OR [Order].OrderID= [ServiceOrder].OrderID
```

But this query only returns data if both [OtherService] and [ServiceOrder] tables contains any data. but If there is no data in one of the tables, query doesn't retrieve data even if the other tables contain some data.

For example, say I have couple of records in [OtherService] table but I don't have any data in [ServiceOrder] table, this query should bring all the data that are in [OtherService] table right? but it does not retrieve any record even though I have record in [OtherService] tables. Why is that?

Comment: Do you want to return rows where there is only data in Order, or should there be data in at least one of OtherService or ServiceOrder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop using old-style joins and please use the schema prefix. Your query should be:

```
SELECT o.[SrvcDate], o.OrderID, o.[EmployeeID], o.[CustID], o.[ComputerID]
--, I assume some columns from OtherService / ServiceOrder
FROM dbo.[Order] AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[OtherService] AS os
ON os.OrderID = o.OrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[ServiceOrder] AS so
ON so.OrderID = o.OrderID;
```

If you want there to be at least one row in either `OtherService` or `ServiceOrder` then add:

```
WHERE COALESCE(os.OrderID, so.OrderID) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: +1 because of the where clause (it just seems that the OP wants that, but I could certainly be wrong).

Comment: Yea that where clause is what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should do proper explicit joins, in this case, outer joins. Currently you are doing implicit inner joins, so it will only retrieve rows that exists on the three tables.

```
SELECT [SrvcDate], O.OrderID, [EmployeeID], [CustID], [ComputerID]
FROM [Order] O
LEFT JOIN [OtherService] OS
ON O.[OrderID] = OS.[OrderID]
LEFT JOIN [ServiceOrder] SO
ON O.[OrderID] = So.OrderId
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Using Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The nulls that result from this are killing you.  My guess is that you want something like:

```
SELECT [SrvcDate], [Order].OrderID, [EmployeeID], [CustID], [ComputerID]
FROM [Order]
LEFT JOIN [OtherService] ON [Order].[OrderID] = [OtherService].[OrderID]
LEFT JOIN [ServiceOrder] ON [Order].[OrderID] = [ServiceOrder].[OrderID]
WHERE [OtherService].[OrderID] IS NOT NULL
OR [ServiceOrder].[OrderID] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Yea that where clause fixed the problem. Thank you.